# How to avoid this error ERROR InternalError: too much recursion Angular 128?

Tags: angular, webpack

i'm new in angular i'm trying to get the data from the model but unfortunately , i got in a console log  errors message as below :

```
ERROR InternalError: too much recursion    core.js:6228:19
    Angular 128
leaveView
        renderView
        renderComponent
        renderChildComponents

InternalError: too much recursion           main.ts:12:24 
    Angular 128
leaveView
        renderView
        renderComponent
        renderChildComponents
```

i believe that is something that related to the web-pack but unfortunately, i can't find out what is the problem to resolve this issue .

i really appreciate your help

```html
<!---html Component  -->
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <button class="btn btn-success">New receipe</button>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item clearfix" *ngFor="let rec of recipes">
            <div class="pull-left">
                <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">{{rec.name}}</h4>
                <p class="list-group-item-text">{{rec.description}}</p>
            </div>
            <span class="pull-right">
                <img [src]="rec.imgePath" alt="{{rec.name}}" class="img-responsive" style="max-height: 50px;">
            </span>
        </a>
        <app-recipe-item></app-recipe-item>
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
<!--- ts  Component -->
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Recipe } from '../recipe.model'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-recipe-list',
  templateUrl: './recipe-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./recipe-list.component.css']
})
export class RecipeListComponent implements OnInit {
  recipes: Recipe[] = [
    new Recipe('a test', 'this  is simply a  text', '/https://www.gimmesomeoven.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Cajun-Jambalaya-Recipe-with-Andouille-Sausage-Shrimp-and-Chicken-32.jpg')
  ];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

```js
export class Recipe {
    public name: string;
    public description: string;
    public imgePath: string;

    constructor(name: string, desc: string, imgePath: string) {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = desc;
        this.imgePath = imgePath;
    }
}
```

Comment: And what's `app-recipe-item`?

Comment: Thanks , ,mbojko , i was added the selector in the app-recipe-item in his html component , so that was the reason for the problem , i removed it and the code is working now thanks :D